# Create a PostGIS raster using GDAL and Python?

Tags: python, postgis, raster, gdal

I'd like to create a PostGIS raster using GDAL and python.

I can get the driver easily:

```
drv = gdal.GetDriverByName("PostGISRaster")
```

But how can I create a new raster table? I can't find any information about `drv.Create` to explain what to put there....?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the ability to create rasters is [not yet available](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/frmts_wtkraster.html) in the driver. However, you can create a layer using your standard PostgreSQL Python driver (i.e. psycopg2) and then open it from GDAL.

So you'd create a layer using [ST_MakeEmptyRaster](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_MakeEmptyRaster.html) and [ST_AddBand](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_AddBand.html):

```
CREATE TABLE rtest (gid serial primary key, rast raster);
INSERT INTO rtest (rast) VALUES (ST_AddBand(ST_MakeEmptyRaster(100, 100, 1, 1, 2), '8BUI'::text));
```

Then you'd open and manipulate the raster in GDAL/Python

```
ds = gdal.Open('PG:host=localhost dbname=mydb table=rtest user=myuser')
```

I haven't tested this extensively yet, but it <del>seems to work.</del> doesn't work at all. I get the error,

```
Writing through PostGIS Raster band not supported yet
```

when I try to write.

You could use Python and psycopg2 to write chunks of your image to a raster table using [ST_SetValues](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_SetValues.html).

Comment: yeah...but you wouldn't be able to write pixel values to the raster (without explicitly using postgis functions), right?

Comment: Hah, you're right. I didn't test that one crucial step. Made a small edit to my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Recently came across this and it ended up helping me, so I thought I would share an update.

Adding additional arguments help as well as adding raster constraints to the table you are trying to use.

```
ds = gdal.Open('PG:host='' dbname='' schema='' table='' user='' port='' password='' column='' mode=2')

SELECT AddRasterConstraints('raster_table'::name, 'column_name'::name);
```

Hope this helps someone else too with the added details.